# Indirect in dative

Tags: preposition, dative

> Was zeigen Sie Ihrem Besuch? (What do you show in your visit?)
>
> Das Kino gefällt unserem Besuch. (We like to go to the movies in our visit.)
>
> Zwei Gedanken sind der gelernten Buchdruckerin Lisa immer wieder durch den Kopf gegangen. (Two ideas have always been going again through the head of the skilled book producer Lisa.)

Are the translations correct? Can you remove dative as well as accusative prepositions and put the indirect in the dative case?

Comment: Careful: "Besuch" here is not "visit", but "visitor(s)". Perhaps you would like to re-evaluate your question? And you might want to look up "Buchdrucker(-in)" while you are at it. That said - welcome to the site. Don't forget to take the [tour] and visit our [help] to get a better understanding if how this site works!

Comment: In German the first word of every sentence must be written with an uppercase first letter (this is same as in Englisch) (»Was ...«). In German also EVERY noun must be written with an uppercase first letter (»Kino«, »Buchdruckerin«, »Lisa«, »Kopf«).

Comment: I really don't know what you're asking. You last sentence confuses me a lot. But other than that, it looks pretty much like a translation proofreading of an individual text without any specific issue. Off-topic either way.

Comment: Besides, do you mind using proper capitalization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my translations:

> Was zeigen Sie bei Ihrem Besuch?
>
> Wir würden *bei unserem* / *während unserem* Besuch gerne ins (in das) Kino gehen.

The last sentence is almost correct, just some spelling mistakes. And I would use *talentiert* instead of *gelernt* for *skilled*:

> Zwei Gedanken sind der talentierten Buchdruckerin Lisa immer wieder durch den Kopf gegangen.

And as Stephie said: *Der Besuch* can be *the visit* or *the visitors*.

Comment: I didn't understand why "our visit" would be in dativ, "our vistor" works. Thanks.